# Adding a navbar in my jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, pug

I am using nodejs,express, and bootstrap.

So this seems like a pretty general question, but I can't find exactly what I am looking for anywhere. I have a layout.jade file and a index.jade file, and I am using my layout in my index.jade file. The problem is, I can't get my navigation bar to show up... here is my code:

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title

    block styles

        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/static/bootstrap.css')

  body

    block navBar
        div.container
            ul.col-md-12.row
                a(href="#")
                    li.col-md-3.col-md-offset-1 Register
                a(href="#")
                    li.col-md-3 Login
                a(href="#")
                    li.col-md-3 About Chatbox
    block content
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block append styles

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/homePage/style.css')

block navBar     

block content

    div.box
        h1.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4 Chatbox
```

What am I not understanding about templates here? I assumed that whatever was under the block portion would just be inserted into the page, and since block content is not inside of navBar, I could just add to the content like it was under the navBar.

The only thing that shows up is the stuff I put in block content in my index.jade file. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `extends layout` in your index.jade file it means that everything in the layout.jade file will be included.

Blocks are used for when you want to change the code depending on which file is being rendered. In this case you are saying that in layout.jade the `block navBar` should contain:

```
div.container
            ul.col-md-12.row
                a(href="#")
                    li.col-md-3.col-md-offset-1 Register
                a(href="#")
                    li.col-md-3 Login
                a(href="#")
                    li.col-md-3 About Chatbox
```

Then in your index.jade you are defining `block navBar` again and overwriting the definition in layout.jade. And since the `block navBar` doesn't have any content in your index.jade, nothing is being rendered and you should simply remove the `block navBar` declaration from your index.jade.

```
block navBar     
  //nothing here means you are telling it to be empty.
block content
```

Basically it means that if you know you are going to use the navbar everywhere you don't need a block for it at all as long as you declare it in your layout.jade and use `extends layout` in all your other files. Only use blocks for the code that changes from page to page.